# Calling cv::calibrateCamera() failed

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to get the cameraMatrix from the function cv::calibrateCamera(), actually I'm not sure if I did it right or not, my initial idea is that:

1. Get two input images which come from the same camera.
2. Extract all the feature points from image_1 and image_2
3. Use cv::calibrateCamera() to get the cameraMatrix (don't know if it would work or not)

Here is my code of doing it:

[calling calibrateCamera()](http://pastebin.com/bKZ0RbQ5)

The compilation went through pretty well, but when I ran it, it throws an exception said:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (i < 0) in create, file
>   /home/hjbolide/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1198
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>   what():  /home/hjbolide/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:1198:
>   error: (-215) i < 0 in function create

As I said, I was just trying this method, and try to get the cameraMatrix from it. Don't know where it goes wrong. Any suggestions?

Thanks very much.

Comment: I would start with the example app and work from there

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. I ported a C calibration example from the Learning OpenCV book to use the C++ interface and was seeing the exact error you saw. I changed rvec and tvec to `std::vector<cv::Mat>` and then the calibration worked. Note that the 2.3 documentation marks both rvec and tvec as OutputArrayOfArrays.

Comment: This is still the case with OpenCV 2.4.6.